# Onboarding experience for redesigned apps

Tags: onboarding, redesign, education

Does anyone have thoughts or good examples (or even white papers) about how to approach onboarding experience for complete app redesign? The two considerations that we are trying to balance is help existing users with getting used to the new UI and helping highlight the brand.

The Current approach being considered:
1) Traditional 3 screens (skippable) of the the updated features -- this seems like it would help with customer desire for "branding"
2) Hints when app gets first loaded that highlight the changes in navigation and most used features -- I think this will probably help most with actual onboarding and ramp up to the new UI

Additionally, are you aware of a mixed approach where new downloads will get one onboarding experience while existing app updates get a different more experienced user onboarding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be having already traffic for the app. You need to divide the traffic and run A/B testing, Multivariate testing for different traffic segments.
So think of a situation where you take two different approaches for the onboarding and run two different campaigns for that.
You can easily read your analytics later to find which runs better according to your client base. So you can easily move all of the traffic to the better traversal path of onboarding. There are different A/B Testing, Multivariate tools available for different criteria.

You can also run some NPS to check their experience, also can go for interactive and intuitive surveys

Comment: Thanks. I think the AB testing would be a really good idea. I'll run it by the customer.

Comment: There are lots of tools available online for these testings. Choose according to your criteria. Hope this qualifies as your answer

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a variety of answers. Thanks for responding. :)